# How can color and alpha channels differ in the Image Editor?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, compositing-nodes, image, render-layers

I'm rendering with composition, my goal is to isolate an object, its shadow, its reflection and the background in order to be able to adjust the background image/color, and the intensity of the shadow and the reflection independently.

The final result with Cycles ("Render Result --> Composite") is as on the left side:

[image]

When looking at the alpha channel (bottom) I see it's 0 for the reflection area, which seems incorrect. If the image is saved and reloaded (right side) pixels with alpha = 0 are gone.

The compositing network which may not be optimized as I'm learning how it works:

[image]

I don't understand how the composited image can have an alpha layer not matching what is displayed, and I don't know how to save an image which has the correct reflection area.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Since that you've set Alpha to 0, why are you asking that image has become transparent?

The alpha in PNG is Straight, in Blender - [Premultiplied](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/glossary/index.html#term-Alpha-Channel) so that you have to set up some alpha to get saved in PNGs, for example like this:

[image]

Then you load the image, you will notice some difference:

[image]

But it will be equal if you convert alpha:

[image]

Comment: They appear transparent, because alpha is 0. Png doesn't keep color information in this case in purpose of file compression though